# Does Q.allSettled ever fail?

Tags: node.js, promise, q

I've seen some places in unit tests where a function returns a `q.allSettled()` promise from a function call and there's a `.fail` attached to the promise. But `.allSettled` will call `.then` even if some/all promises are rejected.

Here's an example:

```
function someFunctionToTest(){
  var aRejectedDeferred = Q.defer();
  var anotherRejectedDeferred = Q.defer();
  var aResolvedDeferred = Q.defer();

  aRejectedDeferred.reject(new Error("I'm aRejectedPromise"));
  anotherRejectedDeferred.reject(new Error("I'm anotherRejectedPromise"));
  aResolvedDeferred.resolve({awesome:"I'm aResolvedPromise"});

  return Q.allSettled([aRejectedDeferred.promise,anotherRejectedDeferred.promise, aResolvedDeferred.promise])
}

it('should never fail', function(done) {

  someFunctionToTest()
      .then(function (data) {
        should.equal(data[0].state,'rejected');
        should.equal(data[1].state,'rejected');
        should.equal(data[2].state,'fulfilled');
        // throw(new Error('I will trigger fail!!!'));
        done();
      })
      .fail(function (err) {
        done(err);
      });
});
```

Can you provide some examples where `.fail` would be triggered?

Comment: I had not have a look at the source, but it's imaginable that it fails if you don't pass in an array/iterable or something like that.

Comment: @Bergi, no it just calls `.then` with an empty array

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Q.allSettled` cannot fail. See [Q API](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#promiseallsettled) which says

> Returns a promise that is fulfilled with an array of promise state
>   snapshots, but only after all the original promises have settled, i.e.
>   become either fulfilled or rejected.

This is quite clear that whatever promises in `allSettled` do you will still get a resolved promise.

In your particular case the `.then` statement may fail because of the e.g. following line

```
should.equal(data[0].state,'rejected');
```

This may throw an assertion exception which will lead to the fail and you can catch it and run `done();` which is the way to say to the testing tool that asynchronous request has been finished. But this is just a guess. `Q.allSettled` itself cannot fail.

Comment: So, to reiterate what you're saying, `.allSettled` itself doesn't fail, but if something in `.then` throws an unhandled exception then `.fail` will get triggered.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you might want to consider:

1. `Q.allSettled` does not have a `fail` function, it only works with `done()`  which has promise states as a parameter. you should check those states to see if promises are either `fulfilled` or `rejected`. however `Q.all` has a `then` and a `fail` function that you might want to use but no parameter will be passed to `then` so no state will be known.
2. If you catch the errors manually in each one of promises (i.e. implement `fail()` function for each one of promises), the states will be always `fullfiled`, so while using `Q.all` or `Q.allSettled`, either don't catch the errors in promises or throw them again after catching!